# C# UploadString not working

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

```
WebClient WbClient  = new WebClient();
WbClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username,password);
WbClient.Proxy = null;
WbClient.Headers.Add("CIMOperation", "MethodCall");
WbClient.Headers.Add("CIMMethod", "EnumerateInstances");
WbClient.Headers.Add("CIMObject", var1);
WbClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/xml");
string res =   WbClient.UploadString(new Uri(url),"POST",var2);
```

`url` is something like `http:// 12.144.15.15:2344` and `var2` is `proper xml`.The server returns null after 10min.What does this mean?

Comment: Use Fiddler and find out what server returns.

Comment: i tried using powershell scripting..the server responds properly

Comment: yes..i did only one function and hardcoded the inputs.it worked.Now i've included in main program.Its even working there.thnks for ur help:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your XML to string this method accepts second parameter (data type string) as string.

```
string res =   WbClient.UploadString(new Uri(url),var2);
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadstring%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: it returns 
    System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path

Comment: @user2940249 Can you post your updated code what you tried after this question

Comment: @user2940249 `http:// 12.144.15.15:2344` Hope it's a typo if not remove space from your URL.

Comment: what is your `var2` Type? Is it XML or string ?

Comment: var2 is string type which contains xml content. the earlier error was from another part of code.
this is the actual error
System.WebException: the connection attempt failed because the connected party did not respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: Yup that's what i thought , However follow this link for your exception http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144236(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @user2940249 Is that path you said is accessible ? Have you tried to ping ?

Comment: yes.the path is accessible.i tried using powershell script.the server responds properly